# Rails 4 and Jbuilder, how to call to_builder method for a collection of models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I've defined a `to_builder` method on my `Location` model. Here's the method:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_builder
    Jbuilder.new do |json|
      json.(self, :id, :latitude, :longitude, :name, :description)
    end
  end
end
```

If I select a `Location` from the database, I can convert it to JSON like this:

```
Location.first.to_builder.target!
```

This works great. How can I do the same thing for a collection of `Location` models? For example, if I get multiple from the database via a relation (an `Area` `has_many :locations`).

```
locations = Area.first.locations
```

Is there an easy way to convert `locations` to json with Jbuilder? My current solution is to define a helper method that will convert models or collections to json for me.  For example:

```
def json_for(object)
  if object.is_a? ActiveRecord::Relation
    a = object.map do |o|
      o.to_builder.target!
    end
    "[#{a.join(',')}]".html_safe
  else
    object.to_builder.target!.html_safe
  end
end
```

Then I would call `json_for locations`. But this does not feel like the right way to handle it.

**UPDATE**

I haven't yet found a great solution to this. Currently I am using a helper that I wrote to render the content of a JSON view. Here's what the helper looks like:

```
def json_for(view, locals_hash = {})
  render(template: view, formats: [:json], locals: locals_hash).html_safe
end
```

Then, I use the helper like this in a view, passing in whatever variables are used in the view:

```
<%= json_for 'locations/index', { locations: @locations } %>
```

I also have a helper for partials:

```
def json_for_partial(partial, locals_hash = {})
  render(partial: partial, formats: [:json], locals: locals_hash).html_safe
end
```

So in summary, I am not using the `to_builder` method at all. Instead, I'm creating the actual jbuilder view files, and then using a helper to render the JSON they generate wherever I need it within my app.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? i'm currently trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @cvshepherd check my update. It's not really a "solution" but it's what I'm currently doing to get what I need. Maybe it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the collection to render as an array that leverages your to_builder override like this:

```
Jbuilder.new do |json| 
  json.array! locations.map do |l|
    l.to_builder.attributes!
  end
end.target!
```

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/139

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/75